# PHP sprintf %d behaviour

Tags: php, printf

Is it safe to assume that `%d` will always try to cast the parameter to an integer when using `sprintf` in PHP?

For example:

```
<?php

echo sprintf('Hello %d', 'foo');
echo sprintf('Hello %d', -1);
echo sprintf('Hello %d', 1);
echo sprintf('Hello %d', 0.1);
echo sprintf('Hello %d', true);
echo sprintf('Hello %d', false);
echo sprintf('Hello %d', null);
echo sprintf('Hello %d', array('foo'));
echo @sprintf('Hello %d', new stdClass());
```

I am not using this to prevent SQL injections (already have parameterized queries in my application) but rather to construct query parameters in a URL.

Comment: It's clearly [documented](http://php.net/sprintf): `Variables will be co-erced to a suitable type for the specifier`. Passing an object to something that expects a string(say) will require the object to implement the magic __toString() method, however. PHP will not be able to convert ALL types, just ones it knows how to do so.

Comment: @MarcB Oops I missed the table in the documentation. If you want to put that as an answer then I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly [documented](http://php.net/sprintf): `Variables will be co-erced to a suitable type for the specifier`.

Passing an object to something that expects a string(say) will require the object to implement the magic `__toString()` method, however. PHP will not be able to convert ALL types, just ones it knows how to do so.